# MSBuild 16 and Windows Server 2012 r2 - long path error

Tags: msbuild, windows-server-2012-r2, long-path

I am having an issue after updating to the newest version of *MSBbuild (16.5.0+d4cbfca49)* on *Windows Server 2012 R2*.

When I run a build in a deep folder structure (up to 150 chars in length), the build fails because a project reference cannot be found. It turns out that the reference path is more than 260 chars long. Strangely the same project can be built with and older *MSBuild version (15.9.21+g9802d43bc3)*.

Another observation is that if the project is moved to a shallower folder structure with shorter paths, the build works smooth.

The long path registry key is set but it seems it does not help. Any ideas please?

Comment: [related](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/53).

Comment: Thx, I am aware of that already